# When I try delete a row in database return already using error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I want to delete a row in database with c#. But it's return that:

> Can't update table 'medikal' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

C# Code:

```
 using (MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(db_name + ".delete_medikalislem", connect))
            {
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_id", medikal_id);
               connect.Open();
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               connect.Close();
            }
      }
```

Stored Procedure Code:

```
DELETE FROM medikal WHERE islem_id = p_id;
```

After Delete Trigger Code:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE tl_ integer default 0;
DECLARE usd_ integer default 0;
DECLARE eur_ integer default 0;
DECLARE gbp_ integer default 0;
DECLARE toplam_ integer default 0;

SELECT tl, usd, eur, gbp INTO tl_, usd_, eur_, gbp_ FROM medikalfirmalar WHERE isim = OLD.medikal_isim;
DELETE FROM medikal_caritahsilat WHERE islem_id = OLD.islem_id;
    IF (OLD.birim='TL') THEN
    SET toplam_= tl_ - OLD.tutar;
    UPDATE medikalfirmalar SET tl = toplam_ WHERE isim = OLD.medikal_isim;
    END IF;
    IF (OLD.birim='USD') THEN
    SET toplam_= usd_ - OLD.tutar;
    UPDATE medikalfirmalar SET usd = toplam_ WHERE isim = OLD.medikal_isim;
    END IF;
    IF (OLD.birim='EUR') THEN
    SET toplam_= eur_ - OLD.tutar;
    UPDATE medikalfirmalar SET eur = toplam_ WHERE isim = OLD.medikal_isim;
    END IF;
    IF (OLD.birim='GBP') THEN
    SET toplam_= gbp_ - OLD.tutar;
    UPDATE medikalfirmalar SET gbp = toplam_ WHERE isim = OLD.medikal_isim;
    END IF;
END
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this delete trigger fire on the `medikal_caritahsilat` table?  If so, then you are giving a recursive trigger definition, and MySQL does not support this.  You will have to find some other way to implement your logic.

Comment: you can try doing before delete instead of after delete